# Massive query with predicate questions

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am working in a specific project to change my repository to hazelcast.
I need find some documents by data range, store type and store ids.
During my tests i got 90k throughput using one instance c3.large, but when i execute the same test with more instances the result decrease significantly (10 instances 500k and 20 instances 700k).
These numbers were the best i could tuning some properties:

- **hazelcast.query.predicate.parallel.evaluation**
- **hazelcast.operation.generic.thread.count**
- **hz:query**

I have tried to change instance to c3.2xlarge to get more processing but but the numbers don't justify the price.

How can i optimize hazelcast to be more fast in this scenario?
My user case don't use map.get(key), only map.values(predicate).

**Settings:**

- Hazelcast 3.7.1
- Map as Data Structure;
- Complex object using ***IdentifiedDataSerializable***;
- Map index configured;
- Only 2000 documents on map;
- Hazelcast embedded configured by Spring Boot Application (singleton);
- All instances in same region.

**Test**

- Gatling
- New Relic as service monitor.

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your use-case only contains map.values with a predicate, I would strongly suggest to use object type as in in-memory storage model. This way, there will not be any serialization involved during Query execution.

On the other end, it is normal to get very high numbers when you only have 1 member. Because, there is no data moving across network. Potentially to improve, I would check EC2 instances with high network capacity. For example c3.8xlarge has 10 Gbit network, compared to High that comes with c3.2xlarge.

I can't promise, how much increase you can get, but I would definitely try these changes first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using object type as in-memory storage model.
I am doing all best practices according to this post: 
http://blog.hazelcast.com/for-faster-hazelcast-queries/
i think that micro services scale strategy is horizontal not vertical.